# Actual packet generation using scapy

Tags: python, security, wireless, scapy, sniffing

I am trying to generate packet using Scapy as :
`send(IP(dst="151.189.13.35", src="192.168.0.103")/UDP(sport=5555, dport=53))`

Result shows: Sent 1 packet. But I want to know whether this packet is being sent to given destination address, why it is not being captured by my wireless sniffer?

Other one I have tried to send more packets (loop) 'p=sr1(IP(src="192.168.0.103", dst="151.189.13.35")/UDP (sport=[5555], dport=[53])/"Xyz") ' , still not single packet captured by wireless sniffer.

I am using scapy`s sniff function as sniffer on wlan0 interface, enabling monitor mode on it (mon0) using airmon-ng. Sniffer is on one system and packets are being generated on other system.

Comment: What sniffer are you using? Wireshark? Be sure you are sniffing on the correct interface. Try sniffing in promiscuous mode. Please update your answer instead of writing in comments.

Comment: k... i am using scapy`s sniff function as sniffer on wlan0 interface by enabling monitor mode with airmon-ng on wlan0. Sniffer in on different system and I am generating packets on different system.

Comment: Just a guess, try turning off the firewalls if any.

Comment: no firewall is there for my network, just two system having linux os and a Access Point

Comment: Can you ping the systems from each other? Just to be sure if there is proper connectivity between them.

Comment: yes. both system getting response from each other

Comment: Can you please post the code about how are you sniffing?

Comment: def PacketHandler(pkt):                                              if pkt.haslayer(IP): '''getting IP addr here '''                                                               sniff(iface="mon0", prn = PacketHandler)

Comment: well, the first packet you are trying to send is a malformed DNS packet(port 53 is the port used by DNS), maybe your system wont accept a show a malformed packet for some reason.  try sending the packet to another port.

Comment: could you also check with conf.iface command just in case? and also could you set just in case this with conf.iface="desired_interface"?